# Sand like substance between the painted wall and Sheetrock making the walls crack

Tags: drywall, walls, paint

[image]

There is cracking in both the entry way and one bedroom of the house with this sand like substance underneath. I have had no luck looking up why this could be happening and any suggestions for how to fix the cracking. Does anyone else have this issue or know what the root of the problem is or what this sand like substance inside the wall is? I have taken a spackling tool and it falls right off and the Sheetrock is fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it under the paint but on top of the sheetrock? Could it be poorly mixed sand texturing?

Comment: It’s under the paint but on top of the sheet rock that is correct. I am not sure what’s causing it. No one has touched the walls / painted in many many years

Comment: Termites  most likely.          remove a section of sheet rock and inspect for damage to wood framing

Comment: Termites will eat the paper (cellulose) leaving the paint film and the gypsum alone. The sandy gunk is their waste.

Comment: Kris- any suggestions for how to deal with that once we know it’s termites / how to repair

Comment: Termites were my first guess too - but after looking closer at the photo, I'm not sure. You can see where it looks like they were building walls to seal the cracked paint, but then what are the areas in between? Just looks odd.. compared to what I'm used to seeing.

Comment: The wood behind the wall is fine and the wall is not hallow